# Contador de links - sem página externa, utilizando JS onClick() ou outra solução em PHP + MySql

Tags: php, javascript, mysql, link, contador

Olá, busco ajuda para montar um contador de link. Não gostaria de utilizar uma página que de coleta, mas sim uma solução que rode em qualquer página. Exemplo em uma página com 03 links: link01.php, link02.php (que foi clicado) e link03.php, agora que o 02 foi clicado, este recurso pegaria este valor (link02.php) e colocaria em uma variável.

Answer (score 1):

Pode fazer o listener de clicks com o jQuery:

```
$('a').on('click', function(){
    alert(this.href);
});
```

mas para não haver bloqueio da navegação do usuário voce deve salvar no banco em uma chamada ajax:

```
 $('a').on('click', function(){
    var href = this.href;
    $.ajax({
        type: 'get',
        url: 'contador.php?href='+href,                        
        contentType: 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
        success: function(response) {

        },
        error: function(xhr, error) {

        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Olá @marcelobns, verifiquei que há um link contador.php no teu código, eu devo ter uma página onde todos os links vão passar por ele? Desculpe, não está claro pra mim, obrigado pelo retorno.

Comment: @EduardoCorreia o contador.php vai ser onde você vai salvar no seu banco o link que foi clicado